# Battery won't charge 0% Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ASUS GL752VW-GS71

Tags: 20.04, laptop, asus, battery, charging

I am currently running an ASUS RoG GL752VW-GS71 Laptop. I was running Windows 10 for the longest time, but I decided to switch fully to Linux on this machine. I have had the most success with Ubuntu in the past so I figured I would run that. I installed 20.04 LTS of Ubuntu and everything works great! except for the battery. I was low on power when I made the shift and had not realized there were so many issues with the battery charging on Ubuntu. The system refuses to charge the battery. It sees that it is present, but no charge. If I unplug the AC adapter, it dies immediately.

I would really like to get this working on Ubuntu if possible, but to be frank I have never encountered a hardware issue like this.

The Battery is good! so before anyone tells me to replace my battery you need to have a good explanation as to why installing Ubuntu would break the battery. The Battery is also very difficult to remove. You cant just pop it off the back so yeah...

```
jburton-sa@RoG-Laptop:~$ upower --dump
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 27 Jul 2020 10:18:45 AM EDT (435 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 27 Jul 2020 10:24:45 AM EDT (75 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         32.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             15 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            67.625%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 27 Jul 2020 10:18:46 AM EDT (434 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-full:         32.46 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          0%
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.11
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: PowerOff
```

I have tried shutting down, pulling the power cord, and depressing the power switch for a minute. Unfortunately that does not do anything for me. Any original thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think it is Ubuntu causing this? Laptops charge without the OS running.  Charge it up while its powered off, then turn it on while on battery, go to the bios, look at the battery info there and see how long it lasts.

Comment: My reasoning has to do with the fact that it was working on battery power prior to installation of the Ubuntu OS. That is one hell of a coincidence for the battery to magically die the moment you install an OS. So either the Installation of Ubuntu broke the physical battery, or it is a setting somewhere that needs to be configured.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Output is: GL752VW.303

Comment: Your BIOS is current. Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the same problem occurs. Does the battery icon indicate that it's charging? Your charger may be defective.

Comment: @heynnema Same thing in the LiveUSB the icon does say that it is charging, in both, even the upower output above "says" it is charging, but it is not ever gaining a charge.

Comment: As to the charger being defective, I was operating 2 days ago on windows with no issues.

Comment: Because of "I was low on power when I made the shift" and "If I unplug the AC adapter, it dies immediately"... I'd say that it's a hardware problem... probably a bad battery... or bad charger. Do you have another charger to try?

Comment: No, I don't, but I will reinstall windows I guess to prove it isn't the battery.

Comment: Again, you don't need an OS, you can do all testing with the BIOS.

Comment: @rtaft I don't disagree that that "should" be the case. However if it is the battery suddenly went up when installing Ubuntu 20.04lts that leads me to the conclusion that Ubuntu installations break laptop batteries. The battery was fully functional prior to OS installation. Was it older? sure. But it was still holding a charge.

Comment: The other thing that bothers me about this is that there are literally hundreds of threads reporting similar issues with various versions of Ubuntu, and everyone always jumps on the battery, because that is the easy answer. I feel like no one wants to deal with the issue that Ubuntu has an issue with charging batteries. Even if I could do it with the OS off, I shouldn't have too.

Comment: Please report back after the Windows reinstall.

Comment: @heynnema It appears you were both correct, It is now not working in Windows either. This is even more troublesome to me though as now I have to consider that Ubuntu caused a failure of the battery hardware.

Comment: I've been running Ubuntu on an ASUS RoG from the day I bought it 2 or 3 years ago, and the battery is still good, in contrast the battery on my Acer with dual boot, has died after about 4 years, which can be expected. I bought an Asus transformerbook with Win 10 and after several months just after the warranty was up, it had a power problem from faulty manufacture (well documented on the WWW) they told me I would have to pay for the repair myself. So I can well imagine your battery problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Ubuntu had nothing to do with the battery failure. It's expected behaviour for an older battery, with the symptoms that you had.

Answer (score 0):

So the Battery is at fault in this case. However I am still not convinced that the Ubuntu Install did not cause the failure. The battery was working fine prior to the install of Linux. Perhaps it is a combination of old parts and stress. Not sure, but the reason the system is not charging is due to the battery failing.

Comment: Usually what kills batteries prematurely is heat.  Can Ubuntu kill a battery faster...yes, there are many posts that complain that their laptops run hotter in Ubuntu, for various reasons.  I have a few dell models that sitting in a docking station running 24/5 would kill the battery in a year or two.  My HP has a bios option for preserving the battery when docked, and after a year it's held up rather well with Ubuntu.  But in your case, I can't see the OS causing a failure that quickly especially since the OS has no control over the battery.